# GET routers does not called our express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If you have placeholders and predefined routes at the same place, the predefined ones never get called, if the placeholder was declared before the predefined ones.

Example:

```
router.get("/:id", fetchEntry)

router.get("/fancy-action/", doSomethingFancy)

<-- if ordered in that way, fancy-action would call fetchEntry instead of doSomethingFanc
```

Comment: I think this link will help you :- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the most specific routes `fancy-action` before the general one `:id`:

```
router.get("/fancy-action/", doSomethingFancy)
router.get("/:id", fetchEntry)
```

Comment: I think you should accept William Wang answer not mine.

Comment: Thanks, seems @ZohaibQadir doesn't know the two answers can't be accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Define `/fancy-action` route before the `/:id`

```
router.get("/fancy-action/", doSomethingFancy)
router.get("/:id", fetchEntry)
```

Comment: by the way, why is this happening? Is there any documentation available for routes?

Comment: Parth Raval already provided - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: @WilliamWang i think he accidentally accepted my answer .